# How do I aggregate the values from two columns and create a new column from it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

How can I sum up the values in column "number" for each state and then create a new column from those values next to "number"?

So far I have this to aggregate:

```
out_state_total['df']=df.groupby('State')['out-of-state'].sum(axis=1)
```

But for some reason I can't create a new column from those values...

```
example state  in-state  out-of-state final_state
red      NJ     3000     99           AL
blue     ND     43       500          AK
green    NY     8000     10           AZ
gray     NJ     94       20           AR
orange   DE     32       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Transform

```
df[['in_state_total','out_state_total']]=df.groupby('state')['in-state', 'out-of-state'].transform('sum')


    example state   in-state    out-of-state    in_state_total  out_state_total
0   red     NJ      3000        99              3094            119
1   blue    ND      43          500             43              500
2   green   NY      8000        10              8000            10
3   gray    NJ      94          20              3094            119
4   orange  DE      32          7               32              7
```

​

Comment: Hm, it says AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'number'

Comment: I wrote this: in_state_total=df.groupby('State')['in-state'].sum() then this: df['in_state_total']=df.groupby('State').number.transform("sum")

Comment: The column names you are using and the ones i see in the df you have posted are different. You don't need groupby.sum, you can directly use transform

Comment: I'm not sure though if the code is correct? So this is with using the correct variables: df['out-of-state']=df.groupby('State').number.transform("sum")

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It should output the values you have in column out_state_total. However, those values come from out-of-state, which would then be put in a new column called "out_state_total". Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I am not sure i get you, it would be better if you post the desired output in the question

Comment: sorry for the troubles... I just updated my original post to show that I would like all 50 states listed once in order and then in-state and out-of-state numbers next to it

Comment: I would then go in and delete rest of columns at the end on my own. @A-Za-z